# Extract float number from a string and add them together. (python)

Tags: python

```
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.6735
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.5474
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8375
```

I have multiple data like this, and I want to extract the float numbers from that text. Then, I want to add them all together. How can I go about achieving this?

edit;
the examples given are from this text file, i have extracted these portions but now i want to extract the numbers only add them together.
https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt?PHPSESSID=bbcdb4b3754dc70f9a331ecab6057a7e

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: Are these rows of data from a file?

Answer (score 4):

If it all is the same format then you can simply do:

```py
strings = ["X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475", "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.6735", "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.5474", "X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8375"] #Split after ": " gives ["X-DSPAM-Confidence","0.8475"] for the first string

#Take the last number index in each splittet string i.e "0.8475" and convert to a number
vals = [float(p.split(": ")[1]) for p in strings] #[0.8475, 0.6735, 0.5474, 0.8375]

sum(vals) #2.9059
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `split` the string with `"X-DSPAM-Confidence: "`.
Assuming you have some newlines or whitespaces you can use `.strip` to remove them

```
x = """X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.6735
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.5474
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8375"""

result = sum([float(i.strip()) for i in x.split("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") if i.strip()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = ['X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475','X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.6735','X-DSPAM- 
Confidence: 0.5474','X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8375']

res = [float(m.split(": ")[1])for m in mystring]
sum(res)
```

if your string order is same then take them as a single string in list form and apply this, it will take the last index from every string and store it as a float number and at the end it will add all elements in it

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need

```
txt = """X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.6735
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.5474
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8375"""

values = [float(value) for value in txt.replace("X-DSPAM-Confidence:    ", "").replace("\t", "").replace("    ", "").split("\n")]

print(values)
```